# Returning watch stream using Kubernetes with python client with server sent events

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, stream, kubernetes-pod

I'm new to kubernetes and I wanted to return the watch stream data in JSON to frontend, where they have implemented store which will check the data and display it on UI.
I'm implementing it with Flask and Server Sent Events, I've pasted the code here below, please suggest me if there is any better way to do this or how to return the data using watch. Also how to calculate the age of the pods?

```py
def getpods():

    config.load_kube_config()
    w = watch.Watch()
    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    age_final = '0h'
    ret = w.stream(v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces)
    for event in ret:

        list1=[]
        myjson = {}
        list2 = []
        restarts = 0
        if event['object'].status.container_statuses != None:
            for j in event['object'].status.container_statuses:
                restarts += j.restart_count
            list1.append([event['object'].metadata.name, event['object'].status.phase, restarts, age_final, event['object'].metadata.namespace])
            restarts = 0

        for i in range(0, len(list1)):
            myjson = {'name':list1[i][0],'phase':list1[i][1], 'restart':list1[i][2], 'age':list1[i][3], 'namespace' :list1[i][4]}

            list2.append(myjson)
            jdump = json.dumps(list2)

        print(jdump)


def stream():
    def evesource(): 
        while True: 
            yield 'data: {}\n\n'.format(getpods())
    return Response(evesource(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

Comment: Am I right that you are using the [python-kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) ?

Comment: you can use `event['object'].status.start_time` field and Calculate Age as difference between `datetime.datetime.now()` and the value you got from ret.

Comment: @Nick  Yes, I'm using Kubernetes python client only, I'm using V1CoreApi and this is my client import:

from kubernetes import client, config

Comment: I'll try to get age that way, thank for replying, but how do I return this stream of data?

Comment: I'm trying to implement Server Sent Events for this, is there any particular module or library in python or flask rather than using generators as in the above code?
I read about eventsource module and sse-client, also about using kafka or redis server, which one is better?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Technically, you can use python client for that. It can be found here: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python . There is an example on how to watch object and you can create a json and send it to UI each time there will be an event recorded.